# Incorrect Chain Rule Proof

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have a valid proof for the Chain Rule, however I do not understand why the 'arguement' given here is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It already says why: Consider constant $g$ as an extreme case. Do you see the deathly sin secretly commited in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that if $g$ were constant in a neighborhood of $a$, then $g(x)-g(a)=0$ when $x$ is close to $a$, and thus you are dividing by $0$.

Answer (score 9):

One simple way to fix the problem of "division by zero" when $g(x)-g(a)=0$ is to define the continuous function
$$
\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta g}(x)=
\begin{cases}
f'(g(a))&\quad\text{if }g(x)-g(a)=0\\
\\
\dfrac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}&\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and confirm (think it through properly) that we have
$$
\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{x-a}=\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\cdot\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta g}(x)
$$
both for values of $x$ where $g(x)-g(a)=0$ and other values of $x$. In the first case, both sides becomes zero, and in the second case we are basically considering the dangerous step
$$
\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{x-a}=\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\cdot\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}
$$
which is now legitimate since $g(x)-g(a)\neq 0$. When taking limits, you will need the continuity of $\dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta g}(x)$.

Comment: This avoids treating $g(x)=g(a)$ as a completely separate special case, and avoids introducing [another elaborate mechanism](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1132523/139123), but it does require some careful thought (e.g. about the continuity of $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta g}(x)$).

Comment: I love this idea, but I have a slight hang up and I'm very hopeful that this will still be addressed on a post from several years ago. How do we know that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x) - g(a)} = f'(g(a))$? Is this not separate from the definition of $f'(g(a))$, which is is that $\lim\limits_{x \to g(a)} \dfrac{f(x) - f(g(a))}{x - g(a)} = f'(g(a))$? This would be required for the term $g(x) - g(a)$ to cancel, yet I don't see why we have this. Can anyone point it out to me?

Comment: Wait, wow! I had an epiphany and figured it out! To the original poster of this answer: you are an angel, I've been stuck on this proof for weeks! I don't know why I haven't seen this idea before, it's both elegant and efficient. Here is a typed proof https://drive.google.com/open?id=15rm6Hwoe91eIQnfLrQD8h1enu5-E6hO7 which somewhat formalizes the argument. I f***ing love you for sharing this. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman: I am happy to read about that! An epiphany is such a pleasant moment. I tried to follow the link, but was blocked. Perhaps you could allow access for anyone with the link?

Comment: @String That's actually very good to know, this is the second time I've had trouble sharing links to my Google files. Does it still not work? Maybe this https://drive.google.com/file/d/15rm6Hwoe91eIQnfLrQD8h1enu5-E6hO7/view?usp=sharing will work, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old post, but I'm hoping I might get a response here anyway. As I'm working through this proof, I actually don't see why we need to define Δ/Δ to be a continuous function. It seems to me both that (i) Δ/Δ is always going to be equal to the difference quotient regardless of what value we assign to it in the case that *g(x) = g(a)* and (ii) the limit of Δ/Δ will always approach ′(()) as x approaches a, so I don't see the harm in choosing any arbitrary value for Δ/Δ when *g(x) = g(a)*. Intuitively, I feel that there's something wrong with statement (ii), but I can't place a finger on precisely what's wrong with it.

Edit: Sorry, I meant to post this as a response to another comment, not as an answer. I am new to the website.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Hi, see this PDF https://drive.google.com/open?id=15rm6Hwoe91eIQnfLrQD8h1enu5-E6hO7 which you might or might not still find interesting.

Comment: It seems to me like the answer to your question is that, what we really need is that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta g} = g'(f(a))$. The argument to show that this is true is somewhat similar to the argument that $\dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta g}$ is continuous at $a$. In fact, there's a theorem which states that a function $f$ is continuous at a limit point $a$ of its domain if and only if $f(x) = f(a)$.

Comment: To be more precise (if I am not mistaken), we need that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta g} = g'(f(a))$ in order to prove our desired convergence result, and this happens to be equivalent to saying that $\dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta g}$ is continuous at $a$. Lastly, getting down to brass tacks, it turns out that we require that $\dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta g}(x) = G$ when $f(x) = f(a)$ in order to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta g} = g'(f(a))$ (which is what we really care about). The details are presented in that PDF I shared a link to.

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman: Interesting to see your formal rendition of this! Cheers.

Comment: @Dan: I know that I am really late to this thread (as were you originally). Regarding (i), I believe that is false. When $g(x)=g(a)$ the difference quotient in question is NOT defined. Now we essentially have three scenarios: 1. It IS in fact defined for $x$ in some neighbourhood of $a$, 2. $g(x)=g(a)$ for $x$ in some neighbourhood of $a$, 3. The set for which $g(x)=g(a)$ accumulates at $a$ with $x=a$ as it's limit point. Case number 3 is the hardest and highlights the problem: The split into a product of fractions may not be defined near the limit.