# Proving the chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

First see the first comment on this post

[how to prove the chain rule?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180686/how-to-prove-the-chain-rule)

and this post in general

[Chain rule proof doubt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132510/chain-rule-proof-doubt/1132523#1132523)

So we begin by proving the chain rule by assuming we have $f,g$ where $f$ is differential at $x_0$ and $g$ at $f(x_0)$. We consider

$$\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0}=\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

So we need to avoid the cases where $f(x)=f(x_0)$. Of course, if there are finitely many of them, we just toss them out and we are good to go. So my book defines $y_0=f(x_0)$

$$\frac{g(y)-g(y_0)}{y-y_0}$$
 and, for each $y \in D'$ (the domain of $g$), and defines $h(y_0)=g'(y_0)$ so we have

$$lim_{y\to y_0}h(y)=g'(y_0)=h(y_0)$$ so $h$ is continuous as defined and they assert this gives us our result since the resulting products will have limits and so on.

How do we deal with the case where say $f(x)=f(x_0)$ everywhere? How do we deal with it when there are infinitely many points $f(x)=f(x_0)$. If someone could be very rigorous in proving and explaining the chain rule it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A la Spivak: http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/A37W12/Chain.pdf

Comment: It's not a matter of finite but in removable points.  If f(x) = f(x_0) an an interval the f is constant and the derivative on the interval is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Note that because $g'(f(x_0))$ exists there exists a constant $C$ such that $|g(y) - g(f(x_0))| \le C|y - f(x_0)|$ for $y$ near $f(x_0).$

Two cases: 1. $f'(x_0) = 0.$ Here we have, as $x \to x_0,$

$$| (g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0)) )/(x-x_0)| \le C|(f(x) - f(x_0))/(x-x_0)| \to C\cdot 0 = 0.$$

That gives the desired result in this case.

Case 2: $f'(x_0) \ne 0.$ Then for $x$ close to $x_0, x \ne x_0,$ we have $f(x) \ne f(x_0).$ Here the usual smoke-and-mirrors proof works.

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof proceeds as follows.  We have that $g$ is a differentiable function and therefore we have

$$\Delta g(y)=g(y+\Delta y)-g(y)=g'(y)\Delta y+\epsilon(\Delta y)\Delta y$$

where $\epsilon$ is a function of $\Delta y$ given by

$$\epsilon(\Delta y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{g(y+\Delta y)-g(y)}{\Delta y}-g'(y)&, \Delta y\ne 0\\\\
0&,\Delta y = 0
\end{cases}
$$

> It is important to point out that in the notation we are using here, $\epsilon(\Delta y)$ denotes a function $\epsilon$ of  $\Delta y$, and *not* a number $\epsilon$ multiplied by a number $\Delta y$.

Note that $\epsilon(\Delta y) \to 0$ as $\Delta y\to 0$ and therefore, $\epsilon(\Delta y)$ is continuous as a function of $\Delta y$ at $\Delta y=0$!

Now, suppose $y$ is a differentiable function of $x$, say $y=f(x)$.  Then, we denote $y+\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)$ and

$$\Delta g(f(x))=g(f(x+\Delta x))-g(f(x))=\left(g'(f(x))+\epsilon(\Delta y)\right)\times\left(f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\right)$$

Note that since $f$ is continuous, then as $\Delta x\to 0$, $\Delta y\to 0$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta g(f(x))}{\Delta x}&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{g(f(x+\Delta x))-g(f(x))}{\Delta x}\\\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\left(\left(g'(f(x))+\epsilon(\Delta y)\right)\times \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}\right)\\\\
&=g'(f(x))f'(x)
\end{align}$$

as expected!  And we never needed to worry whether $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)=0$.

Comment: Please let me know how  I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I suggest changing $\epsilon (\Delta y)$ to $\epsilon_{\Delta y}$. It may be a little easier to read.It is tempting to mis-read  it as $\epsilon.\Delta y$... And remove the "!" in case your computer is trying to understand it and thinks it's 1-factorial. (How petty can I get? Very.)

Comment: @user254665 I thought that it could be misinterpreted.  I'll add a sentence that explicitly states that the notation denotes a function of $\Delta y$.

Answer (score 0):

When $f(x)=f(x_0)$, we can substitute $f(x_0)$ with $f(x)$. This gives us

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x))}{x-x_0}$$

We can simplify this to

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac 0{x-x_0}$$

which evaluates to $0$. Since $f'(x)$ must equal $0$ under these conditions, this is consistent with the chain rule, because $g'(f(x))f'(x)=0$ by the zero product property.